# Fast way of conversion of stl vector<bool> to bool * array

Tags: c++, stl

Is there some trick which allows to fast convert `vector<bool>` to `bool *` array ? I have vector that keeps a lot of cells and I have to convert it to `bool *` array. I can do it through for loop but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Do you mean array of bool?  i.e. `bool[]` or an array of pointers to bool?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `bool`, since C++11, yes.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to do this without copying the data from the vector to a raw array.

The reason is because `std::vector<bool>` only stores one bit per element (albeit stored contiguously). Thus, you cannot use the normal trick, which is...

```
std::vector<Foo> v(10);
Foo* p = &v[0];
```

However, this is not such a good idea because of its shallowness. You'll really want a deep copy...

```
bool* arr = new bool[v.size()];
std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), arr);
// ...
delete[] arr;
```

If you don't like to manage your memory yourself, you can use smart pointers.

```
auto arr = std::make_unique<bool[]>(v.size());
std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), arr.get());
```

[Obligatory coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/184b84097080a920)

Comment: The 'trick' (accessing the raw underlying array), in C+11, can be expressed also with the help of `std::vector::data()`, which in fact is not defined for `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @Banex I don't understand your comment. It seems we're agreeing.

Comment: According to the standard, its entirely implementation dependent how they store the data, one bool per bit is not guaranteed! 
The copy speed can be very fast, if the used implementation provides specialized versions for `vector<bool>` (see https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).